# why odoo display date format error when save model data?

Tags: odoo

odoo v13:
I've been working very well before, but I suddenly got the following error when saving these two days.
When I try to comment out the date field, the error disappears, and when I reuse it, it goes wrong again. It can be determined that the problem is the date field, and it is the same error to change the date field to a datetime field. Please help me analyze the reasons.

```
TypeError: format() expects a string or boolean:false parameter function()
{var args=(arguments.length===1&&$.isArray(arguments[0]))?arguments[0]:arguments;var formattedString=this;for(var i=0;i<args.length;i++)
{var pattern=new RegExp("\\{"+i+"\\}","gm");formattedString=formattedString.replace(pattern,args[i]);}
return formattedString;}
```

i view the error code ,in web.assets_common.js file, the 3060 line ,the object _options.format=null and newOptions.format=null then display error.

I test found that all modules( including the system's own)  as long as there is a date field to save, there will be this error.

Comment: Would have been nice to know the code you speak of ;-) especially the commented field your talking about.

Comment: All date fields have this prompt, including the module of the system. I think maybe there's something wrong with the database. I rebuilt the database and  reinstalled the module.now it's ok. thank you！